# DeprecationWarning no Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Olá, 
estou utilizando a versão "pandas==1.0.4" e no meu código abaixo tem gerado o seguinte warning:

```
 MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Passing the minor parameter of set_xticks() positionally is deprecated since Matplotlib 3.2; the parameter will become keyword-only two minor releases later.
```

Segue meu código:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bd = {'DATA': pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01',end='2020-01-01',freq='D'),
      'VALOR' :np.random.randint(1,100,size=(366))}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(bd)
df2['DATA'] = df2['DATA'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.plot(df2['DATA'],df2['VALOR'])
ax.set_xticks(range(0,df2.shape[0],30))
ax.set_xticklabels(df2['DATA'].loc[::30],rotation=90)

ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.5,0.2,0.4,0.4])
ax2.plot(df2['DATA'],df2['VALOR'])
ax2.set_xticks(range(0,df2.shape[0]),110)
ax2.set_xticklabels(df2['DATA'].loc[::110],rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

Alguém saberia me dizer qual a forma correta de utilizá-lo sem que receba esse warning? Tendo em vista que nas próximas versões da biblioteca deixará de funcionar dessa forma que tenho feito.

Obrigado!

Comment: Uma dúvida: na linha `ax2.set_xticks(range(0,df2.shape[0]),110)`, o correto não seria `ax2.set_xticks(range(0,df2.shape[0],110))` (com o 110 dentro do range)? Pois o segundo parâmetro do *set_xticks* é um valor booleano e não um número inteiro

Comment: Olá, era isso mesmo, havia colocado no lugar errado. Muito obrigado.